# Azure cloud - The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'

Tags: linux, xml, azure, apache-camel

My apache camel API container war works as expected on-premise windows machine both on jboss and wildfly, but the same throws the below error on Azure cloud (Linux) environment.

> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-container.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.Run
> timeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from UR
> L location [classpath*:/services/**/*-service-v*.*.*.xml]
> Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreExcepti
> on: Line 20 in XML document from VFS resource ["/content/ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-container.war/WEB-INF/lib/ms-enterprise-product-design-pa
> ckager-provider-202307.0.6.jar/services/epd-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0.xml"] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
> 20; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to imp
> ort bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:/services/**/*-service-v*.*.*.xml]
> Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreExcepti
> on: Line 20 in XML document from VFS resource ["/content/ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-container.war/WEB-INF/lib/ms-enterprise-product-design-pa
> ckager-provider-202307.0.6.jar/services/epd-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0.xml"] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
> 20; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from UR
> L location [classpath*:/services/**/*-service-v*.*.*.xml]
> Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreExcepti
> on: Line 20 in XML document from VFS resource ["/content/ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-container.war/WEB-INF/lib/ms-enterprise-product-design-pa
> ckager-provider-202307.0.6.jar/services/epd-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0.xml"] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
> 20; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from VFS resource ["/content/ms-enterprise
> -product-design-packager-container.war/WEB-INF/lib/ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-provider-202307.0.6.jar/services/epd-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0.
> xml"] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is
> strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declarati
> on can be found for element 'camelContext'."}}

- **Service XML snippet**
  [ms-enterprise-product-design-packager-provider-202307.0.6.jar/services/epd-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="mintTypes" class="com.my.package.metadata.MintTypesProcessor" />
    <bean id="mintRecordIds" class="com.my.package.metadata.MintRecordIdsProcessor" />

    **<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="mint-metadataapi-service-v1.0.0">**
        <restConfiguration component="servlet" producerApiDoc="mint-metadata-service-v1.0.0.json"
            bindingMode="auto" enableCORS="true" />
        <rest path="v1.0.0/packager/mintdata/metadata" id="meta-metadata.service.restlet">
            <get uri="/types" id="getMintTypes" bindingMode="off">
                <to uri="direct-vm:metadata-getMintTypes" />
            </get>
            <get uri="/recordIds" id="getMintRecordIds">
                <param name="type" type="query" required="true" />
                <to uri="direct-vm:metadata-getMintRecordIds" />
            </get>
        </rest>

        <route id="direct-vm.metadata-getMintTypes">
            <from uri="direct-vm:metadata-getMintTypes" />
            <process ref="mintTypes" />
        </route>
        <route id="direct-vm.metadata-getMintRecordIds">
            <from uri="direct-vm:metadata-getMintRecordIds" />
            <process ref="mintRecordIds" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```